# Unable to refresh new tab in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension which replaces the new tab page, when I refresh the page it shows me file not found. Can anybody tell how to fix this issue? Is this has to do with either page history or file naming convention? I have index.html set in manifest.json:

```
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  }
```

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions set? Try to check this article to see if it helps out. https://paul.kinlan.me/creating-a-new-new-tab-page-for-chrome/

Comment: Posted the solution :) anyways thanks Mikkel

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
<base href="/">
```

To

```
<base href="/index.html">
```

And it works!

Comment: This answer is not useful because your question does not contain enough information to determine that this is a solution. Someone would have to be psychic in order to get this answer from what is currently contained in your question.  Please edit the question to include enough information to show that this is actually the answer to the problem.