# ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND when a custom Google Chrome new tab extension is refreshed

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a Google Chrome new tab extension using Angular. Everything is working perfectly. I can load the extension every time I open a new tab. However, when I try to refresh/reload the page, I get `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` error. So far, I tried to change the base URL from `/` to `/index.html` which was suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277357/unable-to-refresh-new-tab-in-my-chrome-extension) in StackOverflow, but no luck.

Here's my `manifest.json`

```
{
    "name": "AnExtension!",
    "description": "Descr",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "index.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "bookmarks"
      ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

I also tried to create an extension with React (just used what `create-react-app`) but there was no such problem. Reload/refresh was working fine.

Comment: Sounds like one of your Angular routes is missing or pointing to the wrong path. Instead of guessing, use devtools to debug the problem. You will probably see the incorrect path in the network panel when you refresh the page.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't use Angular Router. Also, not sure how to debug this. When reloading the page with "Reload" button in Chrome, in the network tab of developer tools, I don't see a path or anything like it.

Comment: @wOxxOm, no luck, mate :/ still the same. I don't see it. However, I don't think it is Angular related, because I have no such error when running the app on localhost. The issue is when I use it as Chrome extension loaded as unpacked extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm The thing is there's no error in the console. I am not sure but I think the issue is not with Angular.

Comment: Where do you get ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND?

Comment: Google Chrome shows it. It's Chrome's error screen. This is what I see on the opened page. 
"Your file was not found
It may have been moved or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: Then it definitely means your JS code redirects `window.location` to a non-existent html file.

Comment: Indeed it was the issue! But it is still not working. I managed to fix it, but now it adds a `/` to the end of the link which makes it still unreachable. When I try the one on the  link without the slash, it works and reloads fine.

Comment: I ended up removing the whole Angular router from the project and it worked! Even though I wasn't using it, it was affecting the app. Thanks for the help @wOxxOm

Comment: I have the same problem. I solve it by removing base tag  `<base href="/">` from index.html.

Comment: I have the same issue. In my case it is working on Chrome for mac os, not working for Windows Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this working in an Angular 9 based new tab web extension with the following modifications.

1. Set the base href like so:

   `<base href="./index.html" />`
2. Changed to hash-based routing by setting the following in `app.routing.module.ts`:

   `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, useHash: true })`

Without this setup, I observed two issues. On Chrome reloading the new tab gave the `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` error as per the original issue. Additionally on Firefox, the new tab extension was showing a `moz-extension://...` URL in the address bar instead of a blank address bar when the new tab was opened.

Comment: This worked for me, but I still don't get why this means the page worked but not on refresh. Are you able to explain?

Answer (score 0):

In the comments I read and it worked for me too just removing the base href tag

does not work:

```
<base href="/">
```

does not work:

```
<base href=".">
```

works (aka just delete it):

```
<!--<base href="/">-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I use vue. The reason is that vue-router is faulty. The URL of newtab is changed from chrome://xxxxx/index.html to chrome://xxxxxxxxx. After refreshing, it cannot be found.

Solve the problem use Hash-mode :https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#hash-mode